# Tyring to understand WSGI interface in Django

Tags: django, wsgi

I was recently trying to undestand the what is WSGI application:

> a WSGI application is just a callable object that is passed an environ
>   - a dict that contains request data, and a start_response function that is called to start sending the response.
>
> In order to send data to the server all you have to do is to call
>   start_response and return an iterable.
>
> So, here's a simple application:
>
> ```
> def application(environ, start_response):
>     start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
>     return ['Hello World!']
> ```

The Djangos wsgi.py is

```
"""
WSGI config for basic_django project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'basic_django.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

But when i see the wsgi.py the `application = get_wsgi_application()` callable does not get passed with `environ` or `start_response` function

So how to understand this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't see what is passed to `application` - that's WSGI container's job, not yours. Yours is to *define* `application` as something that can *be passed* those two arguments.

There are various ways to make a callable. The simplest is a function:

```
def add5(x):
    return x + 5
```

Another is an anonymous function, or lambda:

```
add5 = lambda x: x + 5
```

Yet another is an object of a class that has a `__call__` method:

```
class AdderOf5:
    def __call__(self, x):
        return x + 5

add5 = AdderOf5()
```

And you can wrap any of these into a function that returns a callable:

```
def make_add_y(y):
    def add_y(x):
        return x + y
    return add_y
add5 = make_add_y(5)
```

or

```
def make_add_y(y):
    return lambda x: x + y
add5 = make_add_y(5)
```

The third option doesn't exactly need a wrapper, because the class is already a factory:

```
class AdderOfY:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

    def __call__(self, x):
        return x + self.y

add5 = AdderOfY(5)
```

And I guess we could even make a function that would construct a callable object and return it to us:

```
class AdderOfY:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

    def __call__(self, x):
        return x + self.y

def make_adder(y):
    return AdderOfY(5)

add5 = make_adder(5)
```

All of these show how to *define* a callable. How the callable is *invoked* is a different piece of code, and it looks the same, whichever way the callable was defined:

```
eight = add5(3)
```

You can try and verify that this line will work, whichever way we constructed `add5`.

---

Back to WSGI: The example that you provided creates a simple function that accepts two parameters.

Django's `get_wsgi_application` function is a wrapper that returns a callable of the same form: one that can be given environment and start response.

If you want to see how it is defined, here's how it looks:

[`get_wsgi_application`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e0998a460ac15464bcdb048ebc52eae0bb1cbd38/django/core/wsgi.py#L5):

```
def get_wsgi_application():
    # ...
    return WSGIHandler()
```

[`WSGIHandler`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e0998a460ac15464bcdb048ebc52eae0bb1cbd38/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py#L122):

```
class WSGIHandler(base.BaseHandler):
    # ...
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        # ...
```

You can notice it looks almost exactly the same as my last example: a function that constructs a callable object. The callable object can be invoked with two parameters: `environ` and `start_response`.

On the invocation side, which is *not* in your code but in the WSGI container (such as Apache's `mod_wsgi`, or in gUnicorn...), it would look like this, whether you use a simple function (like in your first example) or a callable object (like in Django):

```
response = application(environ, start_response)
```